# Passing JSON Object to React Hook

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to figure out how I can pass the JSON object returned from my server to the react hook to update a state, but I am coming across an error stating that objects are not valid. Does this mean that I would have to pass this as an array or a string? I tried googling around, but couldn't find a straightforward answer.

Here is my error message:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {status, body}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Here is what the JSON looks like:

```
{
    message: {
        body: "User does not exist in the database.",
        status: "error"
    },
    user: {
        authenticated: false, 
        user_id: "", 
        user_email: ""
    }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { SessionContext }  from '../../../contexts/AppSession'

const SignInForm = () => {
    const [{ email, password }, setForm] = useState({ email: null, password: null })
    const [message, setMessage] = useState()
    const { user, setUser } = useContext(SessionContext) // here you are calling a hook at component body
    const router = useRouter()

    const signIn = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.post('/api/auth/signin/', { email, password }, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            withCredentials: true
        }).then((res) => {
            const data = res.data;
            // Set user session state with returned user data
            setUser(data.user)
            // Set the message
            setMessage(data.message)
        }).then(()=> {
            // On successful sigin, redirect to /app/profile/
            if (message.status !== 'error'){
                router.push('/app/profile/')
            }
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
            console.log(err.request)
            console.log(err.message)
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(user)
    }, [user]) // with that console.log will run on every user change

    return (
        ...
    )
}

export default SignInForm;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't render an *object*. It sounds like you're trying to render the `message`, so you'd want to change the section where you're doing something like

```
<div>
  {message}
</div>
```

to something like

```
<div>{message.body}</div>
<div>{message.status}</div>
```

or to

```
<div>{message.body + ': ' + message.status}</div>
```

or even

```
<div>{JSON.stringify(message)}</div>
```

however you want the format to be.